# Посоветуйте фреймворк для работы с протоколом Wialon IPS 1.1?

Tags: node.js, gps

Есть один из сайтов, которому GPS-трекер передаёт инфу, а он (сайт) предлагает услуги ретрансляции. Ретранслирует он по протоколу Wialon IPS 1.1. Чем можно организовать приём пакетов от ретранслятора на своём сервере? Сервер должен «принимать и отвечать по протоколу», как пишут в поддержке. Есть какие-либо готовые фреймворки (желательно nodejs) для этого? Нагуглил лишь одноимённый фреймворк для официального проекта Wialon и тамошнего API. Вообще глухо по сторонним источникам. Или я чего-то не понимаю, и официальный можно использовать для сторонних? У кого-то есть опыт?